# How is oob_score_ calculated in sklearn.RandomForestRegressor?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, random-forest

How exactly is the OOB score calculated for random forest regression in scikit-Learn?

I am aware that it arises from the out-of-bag samples that are not included in the bootstrap sample, but I cannot find any specific description besides [Scikit Learn: OOB Errors for Random Forests](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_ensemble_oob.html), which is specific to `RandomForestClassifier`.

I have also tried doing a wider search for methodology, but the only note I could find on it was on [Page 17 of these lecture notes from Duke University](http://www2.stat.duke.edu/%7Ercs46/lectures_2017/08-trees/08-tree-advanced.pdf#page=17), which states that

> An OOB prediction can be obtained in this way for each of the n
> observations, from which the overall OOB MSE (for a regression problem) [...] can be calculated.

Is OOB mean squared error the method that is used for random forest regression in scikit-learn?

Comment: Here is where it is calculated in the source, if that's helpful
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py#L1050

Comment: @jprebys, post that as an answer; the last line of that function shows that the answer to the bolded question is "no, it's OOB R^2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see here in the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py#L1050), the score is set in the following line:

```
self.oob_score_ = r2_score(y, self.oob_prediction_)
```

So no, it's OOB R^2.